# Stored procedure tries to read uncommitted data inspite of specifying the isolation level to read committed

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a stored procedure which tries to read uncommitted data, inspite of specifying the isolation level to Read committed (*CS).
Below is my stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_TEST_DATA_GET ( IN P_PROCESSNM VARCHAR(17) , 
                                    IN P_Status char(1))
RESULT SETS 1
LANGUAGE SQL
SET OPTION COMMIT=*CS


P1 : BEGIN

DECLARE CURSOR1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
SELECT  DATA
FROM IAS_TEST_DATA
WHERE ( PROCESSNM IS NULL   OR  PROCESSNM = P_PROCESSNM )
AND Status=P_Status ;


OPEN CURSOR1 ;

END P1``
```

I am using Db2 v6 iseries.

How can I avoid reading the uncommitted data, it seems specifying the isolation level in stored procedure doesn't work.

Please advice.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to misunderstand how the transaction isolation works. "Read committed" means just that: this unit of work can only read data committed by others, and waits until locks are released on uncommitted changes. You may want to study [the manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/db2/rbafzmstisol.htm#isol); it says in particular that "any row changed (or a row that is currently locked with an UPDATE row lock) by another activation group ... cannot be read until it is committed".

In DB2 for i v6 and later you can use `SKIP LOCKED DATA` clause in the SELECT statement to accomplish what you seem to want.

Comment: Thanks. Thats precisely I wanted. It works fine if I add SKIP LOCKED DATA clause in the select statement.

Comment: Although what I don't understand is, why does it wait for the locks to be released for the uncommitted data? Shouldn't it just ignore the uncommitted data not read it at all.